# How do I tell Babel-loader to ignore package.json `main` entry?

Tags: import, babeljs, package.json

I'm developing a library of components, which is using Lerna. This means each component directory has a `package.json` file. I also have a `dist` in each of them. That's where the bundle yields to, obviously. My issue occurs while developing. My import statements encounter the `package.json` and try to get the source from dist instead of an `index.js`, where the source lives. How can I mitigate that so the require process avoids the `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apparently I found my answer in Webpack docs, but it wasn't that easy. You have to add a `module` key (in addition to `main`) to let the Webpack resolver know which source to load while in modules environment (development).

See here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields